# Can't install react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook react/lib/getNextDebugID

Tags: reactjs

I get the following error, can I get some help on how to resolve it?

```
npm install --save react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook react/lib/getNextDebugID
```

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
>   npm ERR! Could not install from "react\lib\ReactComponentTreeHook" as it does not contain a package.json file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\chunlinh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-03T19_21_01_657Z-debug.log

Comment: What lead you to use that command?

Comment: From what I saw doing research both dependencies are under react dom. Can you please run 'npm install react react-dom' and check those errors are gone?

Comment: Trying to use adminlte (https://github.com/booleanhunter/ReactJS-AdminLTE), but having trouble, I ended up running the components I needed on my own